# What is the appropriate test for a choice experiment where multiple subjects perform the experiment multiple times?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, choice-modeling

I'm testing multiple subjects in a choice task where they are either right or wrong. By chance they would choose the right answer 50% of the time. Each of my 11 subjects performs the test 24 times.
To test if they perform significantly better than chance I would just add up the number of correct choices X and perform a Binomial test with  n=264 and p= 0.5. Is this approach correct? Do I have to worry about the independence of data points?
Thanks for your help!

PS: Learning over time or something like that is not an issue in this case.

Comment: Some subjects may be better than others, so lumping all $11 \times 24 = 264$ responses together does not seem appropriate. Each person who gets 17 or more right has performed significantly better than average. [If $X\sim\mathsf{Binom}(24, .5),$ then $P(X \ge 17) = 0.032.$ I assume the 24 performances by any one subject are independent.] Maybe start by seeing how many of those subjects you have.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "do I worry about independence", I'd ask myself: would I interpret the results the same (A) if half my subjects had 100% success and half the had 0% success, vs (B) each subject had 50% success.  Suspect not, but an n=264 binomial would treat these the same.  Also, would you have as much faith in one subject carrying out 264 tests.  A simple change would be to count each subject's scores up, and test if they are Poisson-distributed around the expected null score of 5.5.  You'd have a smaller, but potentially more realistic n=11.

Comment: The null score would be 12 instead of 5.5 because it would be half the number of trials and not half the number of test subjects, wouldn't it? Also a Poisson distribution is not symmetrical, whereas the results of the test should be if the null hypothesis is true. 
Also I think we would want to treat A and B the same as we want to know if the deviations from the mean even out or not.

Comment: Sorry yes - I was mistakenly dividing 11 in half, rather than the 24!  Binomial distribution of the per-subject scores would be more symmetrical, also. So something along the lines of 'score=rbinom(11,24,.5);tmp=cbind(score, 24-score); summary(glm(tmp ~ 1, family=binomial))` should get you there, in R.

Answer (score 0):

You could fit a Generalized Linear Mixed Model with a binomial response and the subject as a random factor.

For example, using the function `glmer` from the package `lme4` in R:

```
glmer(cbind(number_of_successes, number_of_failures) ~ treatment + (1|subject), family=binomial, data=df)
```

Comment: As far as I know a linear model is equivalent to a t-test in a two sample example. So wouldn't this then be equivalent to a binomial test if you wouldn't use the subject as random factor?

Comment: @FabianP yes I believe if would be, if not equivalent, then very similar. Minor differences might arise as GLM estimates parameters using ML/REML, but don't quote me as I am not an expert.